# Java SSL Too Much Memory Allocation

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

When downloading large files over swebhdfs, java allocates too much byte arrays and let it go as garbage immediately. Though these are short lived byte arrays they trigger too much small pauses which causes unpredictability on the application.

[image]

The Problem as far as I understand is CipherBox.decrypt re-uses the same byte array for input and output to the call Cipher.update http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/security/ssl/CipherBox.java#469

Most of the Cipher implementations if the same array is passed for input and output allocates a new piece of byte array and returns it. This does not matter if you are not using SSL for downloading large data. In our case we download TBs of data from Hadoop and this causes lots of minor GC pauses.

Had anyone run into this issue before ? I believe only cipher which does not have this behavior is RSA, but RSA is broken for other reasons.

Comment: Hard to see what you can do about it. Your best defence is to use as large application buffers as you can, 16-32k (more is pointless as SSL has 16k records). Why are you using `DataInputStream.read()`?

Comment: @EJP I wrote a test program to reproduce this issue. Original program did not use the DataInputStream and had the same issue. I believe I can file a request to java team to expose an API where output buffer can be passed in as an optional parameter.

Comment: Nobody said that not using `DataInputStream` would solve the problem. You can file your request, if you think you can wait two or more years, but it will be rejected. The buffer you provide is for plaintext: the SSL implementation needs a buffer for ciphertext, and the Java API doesn't give you a way to provide that buffer, whose required length you don't know either.

Comment: Thanks @EJP I will start looking for other workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BouncyCastle does not exhibit this problem. BouncyCastle is fully compatible with JCE SSL implementation.

You can prefer BouncyCastle over JCE by the following code

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```

This solved the GC problem for us.